# How to find Who did some query on the database and when?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have a SQL Server 2008 R2 with a database in it.
How to find a certain query that was executed and from what IP ?

I have tried to go through the transaction logs but I cant understand nothing there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use SQL Server Profiler. It's usually installed by default - look in the SQL Server folder on the Start Menu. When you open it, start a new trace and select the database. In the Trace Properties dialog choose the TSQL template. This will then record all the queries running on the database, along with a whole lot of other stuff. It's not massively easy to track stuff down in here, but look for the BatchStarting events to find the SQL that gets run. Then you should run the procedure sp_who2 on the database so you can match up SPIDs in the profiler to logins.